# JQuery Mouseover and mouseout text on div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to have some text added to a Div where I can add some text if the image is hovered and disappear when mouse is out.

I'm trying this:

```
<script>
$('#image1').mouseover(function() {
 $('#panel').append('<div>This image is very nice.</div>');
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should [try this](http://api.jquery.com/hover/):

```
$('#image1').hover(function() {
    $('#panel').append('<div>This image is very nice.</div>');
}, function() {
    $('#panel').empty();
});
```